# how to parsing Json Array in android?

Tags: android

How to parse the below json.

```
    [
    {
        "products": [
            {
                "description": "USB2.0. 1000 dpi, Double Lens Technology. Black  
           (Red,Orange.Green.Grey),White(Red,Orange.Green,Grey) 
             <\/p>",
                "product_id": "36",
                "name": "New      
            MP-770",
                "product_code": "MO018",
                "images": "productimage\/36",
                "price": "59900",
                "weight": "1.00"
            }
        ],
        "num_page": 1
    }
]
```

Comment: Have you tried some thing?

Comment: First surf yourself in google. http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-json-parsing-tutorial/

Comment: jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("products");
for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
JSONArray json = jParser.getJSONFromUrl(URL);

try {
    JSONObject c = json.getJSONObject(0);
JSONArray json1  = c.getJSONArray("products");                      
status = c.getString("num_page"); 

for(int i=0;i<json1.length();i++){

    JSONObject c1 = json1.getJSONObject(i);
    String des = c1.getString("description");
    String pid = c1.getString("product_id");
    String name = c1.getString("name");
    String pc = c1.getString("product_code");
    String images = c1.getString("images");
    String price = c1.getString("price");
    String weight = c1.getString("weight");

    // creating new HashMap
    HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    // adding each child node to HashMap key => value
    map.put("description", des);
    map.put("product_id", pid);
    map.put("name", name);
    map.put("product_code",pc);
    map.put("images", images);
    map.put("price", price);
    map.put("weight", weight);                         

    fetch.add(map);
}
```

copy paste the code and use it, fetch is your arraylist of hashmap and if any problem persist then let me know.

Comment: Yes i get the data. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Android Build in JsonObject/JsonArray or you can use a library from Google called [GSON](https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/)
Have a look at these two Tutorials: [GOOGLE](https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide) and this [ONE](http://www.javacreed.com/simple-gson-example/)

But please use google the next time, there are thousands of tutorials explaining this to you